# Extract String Between Specific Instance of Space - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to extract the numbers out of the strings below in SQL Server. I have looked at other questions but am struggling to find a solution that will capture the numbers regardless of space indexes. My challenge is extracting these numbers when the number of spaces until the number is not static.

The numbers are always before the last instance of space and before the K.

```
Item Name
----------------------
AA BB CCC DDDD E 1.5 K
CC EEE-EEE 0.5 K
CC EEEEEEE 7 K
CC DD EEE-EEE 0.5 K
DDDD EEE 5 K
DDDD EEE EEE 0.5 K
```

I have tried without luck among other variations:

```
SELECT LEFT(ITEMNAME, CHARINDEX(' ', ITEMNAME)), 
   LEFT(ITEMNAME, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ITEMNAME)) as [Item Name]
```

My desired output would be:

```
Item Name
---------
1.5
0.5
7
0.5
5
0.5
```

Any ideas on how to extract this?
Thanks!

Comment: are your numbers always the next to last element? And is the last element always `K`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not specify. It will always before the last space and the last element is always K.

Comment: Does your string **always** ends with `' K'`? (white space + K)

Comment: @Sami Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @choloboy Alright then, see my answer there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` as

```
SELECT *
FROM T CROSS APPLY
     (
       SELECT value
       FROM STRING_SPLIT(ItemName, ' ')
     ) TT
WHERE TRY_CAST(Value AS DECIMAL) IS NOT NULL;
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee50da98f8bb141a076d8a81ad8e7e0f)**

Since you confirm that your string is always ends with `' K'` and the number is before it, simply use

```
SELECT *, 
       SUBSTRING(ItemName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', itemname), 
                 LEN(ItemName) -
                 (
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', itemname)+
                 CHARINDEX('K', REVERSE(ItemName))
                 )
                 )Result
FROM T;
```

OR

```
SELECT *, 
       RIGHT(REPLACE(ItemName, ' K', ''),
             CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(REPLACE(ItemName, ' K', '')))-1
            ) Result
FROM T;
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cea324ffcc42b5e4d2501981722cf8d7)**

Answer (score 1):

Since it will always be the next to last element and the last element is `K` you can simplify it by removing `K` and taking everything up to the first space.

```
select 
    right(rtrim(replace(item_name,'K','')),charindex(' ',reverse(rtrim(replace(item_name,'K','')))))
from 
    (values ('AA BB CCC DDDD E 1.5 K'), ('CC EEE-EEE 0.5 K'), ('CC EEEEEEE 7 K')) v(item_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in SQL Server, because the string manipulation functions are rather primitive.  But it can be done:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('AA BB CCC DDDD E 1.5 K'), ('CC EEE-EEE 0.5 K'), ('CC EEEEEEE 7 K')) v(item_name)
     )
select t.*, v2.s2
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.item_name, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', t.item_name) - 1, ''))
     ) v1(s1) cross apply
     (values (left(v1.s1, charindex(' ', v1.s1)))) v2(s2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d5f18c54d14b79dd6236d43ece1da6f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess need to play around with pat index to get first occurence and last occurence

```
  SELECT 
  CHARINDEX(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ITEMNAME))
  +
     CHARINDEX(PATINDEX('%[0-9^]%', ITEMNAME))


  FROM TABLE
```